# Microcontroller with different sensors

Tags: microcontroller

I am currently working on a project which requires different sensors and modules (Gyro, load cell, lcd, wifi and ultrasonic) with MCU. But I'm not sure if I have the right connections for WI-FI module. Can you please check the connection of wifi modules? Should RX and TX be connected reversely as I connected in the figure ?
Thank you so much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is far too broad of a "review my design" question to be of any value.  Prototype individual aspects, try them, and then ask individual questions about what doesn't work.  If you really can't prototype, at least ask about what you're not certain about (also as individual questions).

Comment: Thank you, I changed the question :)

Comment: That's not what I meant.  If you want us to check certain connections, give us diagrams of THOSE connections.  At least take the time to highlight them in your image to help us out.  Even better -- like I said, prototype them and try them.  It's the ONLY way you'll get a reliable build

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE, because the answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Comment: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=design+review

Comment: This was my first work on MCU's, so I just wanted to ask several questions, and indicated the specific questions actually.

Comment: I feel like you're refusing to use the datasheets for guidance. I discourage you from doing that. There's a few things like how you have a TX channel going to another TX channel and an RX channel going to another RX channel or how you have no chip select for your SPI bus. _**Please, for your sake, utilize datasheets...**_ It tells you how to properly wire everything up and any design choices you need to consider etc. It will (hopefully) answer any design questions you have. If not, then you need to consult the supplier.

Comment: I understand your point of view, and thank you for your suggestion. I use datasheets but sometimes I cannot understand and find example schematics and designs. That's why I am here actually, ask about what I don't find in datasheets. Or maybe I do not exactly know how to find what I need from datasheets. Regards.

Comment: We're trying to help, not trying to prevent you from getting help.  If this is your first effort with microcontrollers, you're not going about it in a great way.  The ST platform has many very inexpensive and accessible development kits.  Buy one, and try out ONE MODULE at a time.  Aside from hardware, each peripheral will have it's own coding challenges.  You'll have an extremely hard time separating hardware from firmware issues, especially if you tackle your whole system at once.  You'll work hard to put it together, it won't work, and then you'll take a piece-by-piece approach.

Comment: Are you planning to use a Ground Plane? For dependable operations, and for accurate measurements, and for useful bypassing action by the capacitors, you should use a Ground Plane.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Yes, I will have copper ground plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- SPI needs a chip select signal, `SPI_CS` (probably) on ESP-WIFI connected to `SPI1_NSS` on the MCU (`PA15`).
- `BOOT0` on the MCU should be pulled down. If you intend to use the built-in bootloader for field updates, you'd need a way to momentarily pull it up.
- Decoupling capacitors are missing.
- `USART1_TX` and `USART1_RX` should be exchanged. Now TX is connected to TX and RX to RX, which might even damage the ICs if you'd try to use them this way.

Comment: Which decoupling capacitors are missing? Thought I already had them in the design.

Comment: @KingDuken, I found the datasheets of every IC's and other components, modules. If you checked the design, you will see the decoupling caps :) I checked the datasheets of the modules. But he says that there are missing capacitors. So if I hadn't asked this here, probably I wouldn't know there are missing capacitors.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed them at the corner